# Not able to compile

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, rtbkit

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc 4.8, my gfortran just updated to 4.8, some I could not compile it, here is the errors:

```
In file included from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp:33:0,
             from ./jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.h:16,
             from ./jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.cc:10:
 /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp: In function 'typename    boost::tuples::access_traits<typename boost::tuples::element<N, boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >::type>::const_type boost::tuples::get(const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>&)':
 /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:228:31: error: typedef 'cons_element' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME impl::type cons_element;
                                          ^
In file included from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp:21:0,
             from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/multi_array/base.hpp:28,
             from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/multi_array.hpp:21,
             from ./jml/boosting/classifier.h:20,
             from ./jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.cc:14:
 /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/concept_check.hpp: In function 'void boost::function_requires (Model*)':
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/concept_check.hpp:45:113: error: typedef 'boost_concept_check45' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
   BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((Model));

 ^
   typedef typename Array::index_range index_range;
                                       ^
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp:43:37: error: typedef 'index' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
   typedef typename Array::index index;
                                 ^
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp: In static member function 'static void boost::multi_array_concepts::detail::idgen_helper<0ul>::call(Array&, const IdxGen&, Call_Type)':
                                         ^
   In file included from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:79:0,
             from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
             from ./jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.cc:18:
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_format.hpp: In member function 'OutputIter boost::re_detail::format_functor_c_string<charT, Match, Traits>::operator()(const Match&,  , boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type, const Traits&)':

/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_format.hpp:1086:41: error: typedef 'char_type'   locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
   typedef typename Match::char_type char_type;
                                     ^
In file included from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:166:0,
             from /home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
             from ./jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.cc:18:
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_split.hpp: In function 'std::size_t boost::regex_split(OutputIterator, std::basic_string<charT, Traits1, Alloc1>&, const boost::basic_regex<charT, Traits2>&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type, std::size_t)':
/home/rtbkit/local/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_split.hpp:110:57: error: typedef 'match_allocator' locally defined but not used [-Werror=unused-local-typedefs]
typedef typename match_results<ci_t>::allocator_type                        match_allocator;
                                                     ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: ***     [build/x86_64/obj/jml/boosting/tools/boosting_tool_common.3ec7a8f7cea9a8b0de95729f9e9210cd.lo] Error 1
```

What is wrong with my libraries? I checked the version of gfortran is 4.8.

Comment: Try disabling `-Werror=unused-local-typedefs`

Comment: The code has warning, and your compiler flag treat them as error (which is generally good).

Comment: @Jarod42 While true in general, `-Wunused-local-typedefs` is IMO often rather pointless.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to answer the question.  For instance, what does your source code look like?  What about the compiler command?  I will note that the second-to-last line of what you did post says "all warnings being treated as errors," which suggests you don't have **errors**, but you asked the compiler to bail out if it thought you were doing something sketchy enough to qualify for a warning.  And it may be that **you** aren't doing something sketchy, but Boost is.

Comment: @T.C.: I still prefer to remove unused things to have a more readable code. (but here, OP has to work around a non warning free library).

Comment: Where do I add the -Werror=unused-local-typedefs? My Makefile has CFLAGS AND CXXFLAGS

Comment: Same problem. Trying follow https://github.com/rtbkit/rtbkit/wiki/Getting%20Started on clean Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when compiling rtbkit with GCC 4.8.

Finally worked for me:

```
nano /home/rtbkit/rtbkit/Makefile
```

add compiler flag **-Wno-unused-local-typedefs** to CXXFLAGS

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated ...
```

Comment: Could you show us how you did the platform-deps? It might help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136236/compile-with-ubuntu-14-and-gcc-4-8

Comment: Oh, thats a problem (

Comment: I've overcame some difficulties. Here is a clues to them:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6851 -> https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/libs/boost/patches/200-cstdint_missing_include.patch?rev=34635

Another problem:

Makefile.am:4:   while processing Libtool library 'libsnappy.la'
make: *** [install_snappy] Error 1

Solution: 

/snappy/configure.ac

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror])

here remove -Werror

But anyway there is more and more problems. So I installed VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.4.5 and followed instruction under it. GCC 4.6 caused just no problem.

Comment: Thank you. That gave me the idea of updating the submodules.
So updated these:
boost - http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/
snappy - https://code.google.com/p/snappy/wiki/Downloads?tm=2
libcurl - http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
gperftools - https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/downloads/list

Comment: Don't bother using rtbkit with Ubuntu 14.  It only works with 12.04.2 Ubuntu.  Wait for an update of RTBkit first.

Comment: @arikin At time of writing it works fine on Ubuntu 14.04, just follow [these directions](https://github.com/rtbkit/rtbkit/wiki/RTBkit-Deps-and-Ubuntu-14.04).  For the curious, [my article on the subject of the dependencies](http://blog.hostilefork.com/rtbkit-advertising-bidding-toolkit-examined/) might shed light onto what is actually going on, though.

Comment: @HostileFork. Yes. At the time I was using Ubuntu 14.04.0.  Did a step update of the OS to 14.04.5 and kept just one version of gcc and gfortran.  (I just love frozen packaging...) Made a copy&paste install instructions to get everything magically right.